# Why do I see random ActionFailed after condition block in logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps, power-automate

Every so often I have `ActionFailed. An action failed. No dependent actions succeeded.` after condition block. This seems pretty random and goes away if I resubmit the run, as if there was some sort of race condition.

I know that an empty condition branch taken would cause a Skipped result and I know I can handle that by setting **Configure run after** to include Skipped (which for whatever stupid reason is not a default) but I've tried an alternative solution of putting a "no-op" block into empty branch (just a useless compose block) in order to always have success outcome going out of condition as seen below.

Is this because both branches of condition are actually executed in parallel and the not taken branch, if faster, will cause the outcome of condition to be skipped? It's a very counterintuitive behavior (like most of Flows sadly).

[image]

Comment: In my opinion, this error may not related to condition branch, it seems caused by the branch under your "Switch" action. Could you please share more details under the "Switch" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this because both branches of condition are actually executed in parallel and the not taken branch, if faster, will cause the outcome of condition to be skipped

For the question above, I don't think it was caused by `both branches of condition are actually executed in parallel` because we can see the `expression result` of "**Switch**" action show with `updated`. The outcome of condition will not affect "**Switch**" action.

According to some test, the error may be related to the cases under the "**Switch**". If any case under "**Switch**" fails, it will show this error. So please check the cases under "**Switch**" action. As we can see the "**Switch**" spent 5 minutes, so please check if there is a case under "**Switch**" needs much time to do the job and failed with time out.

Comment: You're right. I don't know how I could miss the failure in subsequent actions. Somehow I only looked up.

Comment: For the record there's a Google Calendar action below that sometimes fails with error 429 due to too many requests. Usually Azure will automatically retry after some time but sometimes it doesn't.